# How to grant microphone permission using command line in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, permissions, batch-file

Is it possible to grant microphone permission settings via command line or by using Batch script?

What I asked for can be done with the following steps:

```
1) Windows Settings  
2) Privacy
3) Microphone
4) Choose apps that can use your microphone
5) Enable one of the apps to use microphone
```

[image]

**My Que**: However, what is the command/batch script I can use to perform the above action?

*I need to do it with command line because I am deploying an Universal Windows Platform application to Raspberry Pi. However, Pi doesn't have any user interface to change the settings other than using command line. Currently the app is working, but Pi is not granting me permission to use the microphone.*

Comment: Raspberry pi van run windows ?

Comment: Raspberry pi can run on Linux or windows iot 10. But I can't tag windows iot 10 since my reputation here is less than 300.

Comment: So that is arm windows? I wonder if related to windows mobile.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with that actually. I just want to find out the command the change permission in windows.

Comment: Hopefully someone can help you with that. I don't know answer.